# How to hide port number in address bar for jenkins

Tags: iptables, redirect, port, url

I have setup Jenkins to access on port 80 rather than 8080 using iptables on Ubuntu 16.04 by following [the article on Jenkins documentation](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Running+Jenkins+on+Port+80+or+443+using+iptables). It is working fine and I can access the Jenkins using url `http://ci.mymachine.com/`. Earlier it was `http://ci.mymachine.com:8080/`. Anyway after login to jenkins, it redirect me to the `http://ci.mymachine.com:8080/`. So I can see port 8080 on the address bar. Is there anyway to hide the port number using iptables and show `http://ci.mymachine.com/` ,every time user wants to see `http://ci.mymachine.com:8080` and even jenkins redirection also?

Comment: There seems to be an option to specify the jenkins URL in the [jenkins configuration page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11221238/what-does-jenkins-url-means-in-configuration-settings).

Comment: Thanks @GeraldSchneider. I was able to access jenkins without port in address bar with your suggestion. you can post it an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You find "Jenkins URL" in

> Manage Jenkins -> Configure System.

Find the same in *$JENKINS_HOME/jenkins.model.JenkinsLocationConfiguration.xml*